# Pandas: Style a specific cell based on another column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I want to highlight the cells based on the values of another column in a dataframe. Like in the below example, I want to highlight the prodkey1 and product1 cells if the value of p1_ourproduct is equal to 1, and same for product 2 and 3.

How can I do that?

```html
import pandas as pd

data = { 'prodkey1': [101,102,103,104,105],
    'prdouct1': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    'prodkey2': [201,202,203,204,205],
    'prdouct2': ['f','g','h','i','j'],
    'prodkey3': [301,302,303,304,305],
    'prdouct3': ['k','l','m','n','o'],
    'p1_ourproduct': [1,0,1,0,0],
    'p2_ourproduct': [0,0,1,1,0],
    'p3_ourproduct': [0,1,0,0,1],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom `highlighter` function and `apply` it:

```
import re

def highlighter(col):
    if "ourproduct" in col.name:
        return ""
    else:
        last_digits = re.search(r"(\d+)$", col.name).group(1)
        lookup_column = f"p{last_digits}_ourproduct"
        return ["background-color: yellow"
                if our_prod
                else ""
                for our_prod in df[lookup_column]]

df.style.apply(highlighter)
```

First we look at the passed column's name: if it contains `ourproduct` then return empty string i.e., no styling. Else, get the last digits in the column name with a regex `(\d+)$` and lookup the corresponding `ourproduct` column. Then form a list comprehension: if the value in the corresponding lookup column is 1 (the `if our_prod` part), then return a  background color styling with yellow; otherwise no styling.

to get

[image]

Comment: thanks very much! in my actual dataframe, there are 2 columns in front which are "weekending" and "region", and instead of "prodkey1" and "product1", they are"1st_prodkey" and "1st_product" etc. May I ask how can I amend the function and the regex bit? sorry I am a beginner in coding, not too sure how I can do that.

Comment: @Becky glad to be of help! Change in regex is: `re.search(r"^(\d+)", col.name).group(1)` so that we look the digits at the beginning not at the end. As far as I understand, you'd like to ignore first two columns in styling. Then, you can change the first `if` in the function to account for that: `if "ourproduct" in col.name or "region" in col.name or "weekending" in col.name:`.

Comment: I am getting this error: ValueError: Function <function highlighter at 0x000001CC0BC29E50> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (11,)
Expected shape:   (5, 11)  - is there anything I need to amend in the function?

Comment: @Becky I see, for some reason it doesn't broadcast with the new columns. A remedy is to `return [""] * len(col)` in the first `if` of the function instead of `""` only. This will ensure the resultant shape by returning an empty string for each of the entries for styling.